# Compress the size or reduce the line spacing of a legend in matlab figures

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, matlab-figure

I'm trying to make a legend in a matlab figure that takes less space, in particular vertical size. Ideally, if I could change the inter-line spacing of the legend, this would have solved it, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I've searched around in Mathworks questions and Google. I've even tried to "write" from scratch the legend, but it doesn't work when I try to export to eps.

Is there a way to control the inter-line spacing in Matlab's legend? something undocumented maybe?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to adjust the aspect ratio of the legend:

```
set(h,'PlotBoxAspectRatioMode','manual');
set(h,'PlotBoxAspectRatio',[1 0.8 1]);
```

(Default is [1 1 1]).

You can also play with the exact positioning of the various legend elements.  If h is the handle for your legend:

```
hc = get(h,'Children');
```

Now, hc will be of length 3 x the number of items in your legend.

`hc(1)` is the marker, `hc(2)` is the line, `hc(3)` is the text.

(and so on for subsequent items).

`hc(1)` will have a entry `YData`(vertical position, single value), `hc(2)` also has `YData` (vertical position - vector of two identical values), and `hc(3)` contains `Position` - `[x y z]` vector.  The Y values for all these three should be the same.

**Obtain the y-positions:**

```
yd = zeros(length(hc)/3,1);
for n = 1:length(yd);
  yd(n) = get(hc(1+(n-1)*3),'YData');
end
```

Assuming your legend doesn't have any text that goes over more than one line,`yd` should be evenly spaced steps.  Define a new spacing of your choice, `yd2`.

**Set new positions:**

```
% markers
for n = 1:length(yd2)
   set(hc(1+(n-1)*3),'YData',yd2(n));
end

% lines
for n = 1:3
   set(hc(2+(n-1)*3),'YData',[yd2(n),yd2(n)]);
end

% text

for n = 1:3;
    pos = get(hc(3+(n-1)*3),'Position');
    pos(2) = yd(n);
    set(hc(3+(n-1)*3),'Position',pos);
end
```

**Problem** - this shifts all the text and markers but doesn't change the border box. The easiest way if trying to make fine adjustments is to first define the final size/position of the legend, and then reposition/resize elements within to taste.

Also, you may find that when writing out images MATLAB helpfully redraws the image, resetting your adjustments.  See [this blog post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/multi-column-grid-legend/) on Undocumented MATLAB for info on that.